# Prestashop: how to display messages in the cart

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

i'm working in a quota module for PrestaShop 1.6 and in one of the features is that a need to display a message in the cart's page and in that modal that opens when you add an item to the cart from the home page.

I'm working with the `hookCart` the hook function, `public function hookCart($params)`, is in my module's class. From it I can get the instance of the Controller like this `$this->context->controller`

**My question is how to display messages in these two views?** I tried adding them to the `errors` array. I can see the message but not the way I'm supposed to display. I would like to display in those alert classes from bootstrap.

The views:
[image]

[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: Which two views do you mean? View on the first step of the checkout and a popup that asks you if you want to continue shopping or go to checkout?

Comment: @TheDrot I just added the images in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display a message on the checkout page you can use whatever front controller hook you want. I guess the one that makes most sense would be `displayTop`. We won't be outputting any html to the top but just add a message to the controller's errors array.

```
public function hookDisplayTop()
{
    $controller = $this->context->controller;
    if ($controller->php_self != 'order' && $controller->php_self != 'order-opc') {
        return false;
    }
    /* 
        You can do custom logic here if you want to display message only
        on some conditions or only on specific step of the checkout
    */
    $controller->errors[] = $this->l('Some message');

    return false;
}
```

For the popup the things get messy because:

1. Popup doesn't have an error display area
2. Blockcart AJAX uses weird logic that calls [CartController](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/controllers/front/CartController.php#L424) which includes blockcart-ajax.php which loads [blockcart module method](https://github.com/PrestaShop/blockcart/blob/deaf45cf6d63ba29a1eaf0d8d2030f74e4906bd3/blockcart-ajax.php#L29) which loads a [JSON template](https://github.com/PrestaShop/blockcart/blob/deaf45cf6d63ba29a1eaf0d8d2030f74e4906bd3/blockcart.php#L227) file to output data (???)

One way to do this is to use the hook `actionCartSave`. This hook gets executed on pretty much all cart operations, so we need to make sure we are adding our message when a product is added to cart, uses ajax etc.

```
public function hookActionCartSave()
{
    // If cart doesn't exist or product is not being added to cart in ajax mode - do nothing
    if (!$this->context->cart || !Tools::getValue('id_product) || !Tools::getValue('add') || !Tools::getValue('ajax')) {
        return false;
    }
    /* 
        You can do custom logic here if you want to display message only
        on some conditions
    */
    $this->context->smarty->assign('mycartpopupmessage', $this->l('Message');

    return false;
}
```

Then you will have to modify [themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blockcart/blockcart-json.tpl](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blockcart/blockcart-json.tpl#L101) file to add your message into JSON template.

```
...
"wrappingCost": {$wrapping_cost|json_encode},
"nbTotalProducts": {$nb_total_products|intval},
"total": {$total|json_encode},
{if isset($mycartpopupmessage)}
    "mycartpopupmessage": {$mycartpopupmessage|json_encode},
{/if}
....
```

Then you need to modify [themes/default-bootstrap/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js#L344) and add the following

```
if (jsonData.mycartpopupmessage) {
    $('#layer_cart .alert-message').html(jsonData.mycartpopupmessage);
    $('#layer_cart .alert').removeClass('hidden');
}
else {
    $('#layer_cart .alert').addClass('hidden');
}
```

And at last modify [themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blockcart/blockcart.tpl](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/themes/default-bootstrap/modules/blockcart/blockcart.tpl#L210)
and add alert div

```
<div class="alert alert-danger hidden">
    <button data-dismiss="alert" type="button" class="close">×</button>
    <p>{l s='There is 1 error' mod='mymodule'}</p>
    <ol>
        <li class="alert-message"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Now you should be getting a bootstrap alert inside a popup.

Quite some native prestashop modules haven't been (I guess) updated in years as a lot of them are good candidates for an extensive rework or at least compliant with the MVC workflow which would make modifications like yours much more simple.

Comment: thanks! I'll be implementing and then I come back to give you the feedback.

Comment: you are the best, it worked! Also if you don't need extra formatting you can do this: $this->context->smarty->assign('errors', [$msg]);   then the message will appear also and increasing or decreasing the amount of products in the cart

Comment: @AndréLuiz You can do that as well but be careful and merge the existing controller errors array with your message otherwise your line of code will overwrite any previous errors generated by core controller code.